# Is there any way to define a new route in druapl 7 which start with wildcard

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I implement a hook_menu and I want define a route like this

```
$item['%'] = array();
```

and when user enter url like this **domain/whatever** the word whatever must pass as an argument to page callback function. can any body help me please.

Comment: Why do yo need to do so?

Comment: @Bustikiller I want to have some pages which their path is changes base on their type. for example if I write __domain__/**car** it must gives me **car** as vehicle type and if I write __domain__/**motor**  it must gives me **motor** as vehicle type.So I can work with this types and show user proper data.

Comment: If you want to change your path depending on your content type, you should check Pathauto module.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have a fully dynamic route in Drupal, most modules (including core) loop on content_type to create these kind of routes

```
foreach (entity_get_info() as $entity_type => $entity_info) {
    foreach ($entity_info['bundles'] as $bundle_name => $bundle_info) {
        $path = $bundle_info['admin']['path'];
        $items["$path/fields"] = array(
            'title' => 'Manage fields',
            'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
            'page arguments' => array('field_ui_field_overview_form', $entity_type, $bundle_arg),
            'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
            'weight' => 1,
            'file' => 'field_ui.admin.inc',
        );
    }
}
```

Example at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/field_ui/field_ui.module?h=7.x#n79